# Standard deviation graph in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

Is there a way to plot graphs with +-standard deviation about the mean using the jqplot graphs? I know there are candlestick graphs in jqplot but they do not link each candlestick with each other. What I am looking for is like a line graph with for each point, +- standard deviation is marked on it. Consider this graph for example

http://www.csupomona.edu/~jcclark/classes/old/bio542l/graphics/g-line.gif

Comment: hey tomasz, how did u edit it? i was trying to do it but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is built-in support for this in jqplot.  Your choices are three:

1.) Use what is built in: [the the banded line/confidence intervals](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/bandedLine.html).

2.) Hack it yourself.  After you draw your plot, add additional vertical series for each hi/low standard deviation.  This is the option I would use.

3.) Follow one of the posts [here](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/35/add-error-bar-capability) and modify the candle stick plugin (ohlc plugin) to provide the functionality.

Comment: Mark, is there is way just plot one point? sometimes my graphs can have only one point, when that happens, the graph is not plotted. could i be doing something wrong? is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's actually plotted but I think the builtin axis scaling has trouble  with a single point.  If I set it explicit it works.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/z5eNz/2/

Comment: For the above question, i found that they have worked on a fix for this bug. Will try to implement it and check.